# MYSQL: Fetching latest rows from second table based upon timestamp value

Tags: mysql, sql, select, inner-join

I have a table `table1` `a_id` as `PK`,  `ipaddress`, `create_dt`
Here `ipaddress` is `varchar`, `create_dt` is `datetime`

```
a_id    ip              create_dt
9205    10.10.10.10     2017-01-07 08:03:32
9206    10.10.10.11     2017-01-06 08:03:32
9207    10.10.10.12     2015-01-07 08:03:32
```

---more than 1000 rows

I have another mysql table with following columns `id` as `PK`, `ip`, `check_type` `check_status`, `a_id` and `created_dt`:
Here `a_id` is foreign key from `table1`
and `created_dt` is `datetime`

```
id      ip             check_type    check_status  a_id    timestamp_val
1       10.10.10.10    check1        FAIL          9205    2017-01-07 10:03:32
2       10.10.10.10    check2        PASS          9205    2017-01-07 10:03:32
3       10.10.10.10    check1        FAIL          9205    2016-11-07 10:03:32
4       10.10.10.10    check2        PASS          9205    2016-11-07 10:03:32
5       10.10.10.11    check1        PASS          9206    2017-01-06 10:03:32
6       10.10.10.11    check2        PASS          9206    2015-01-06 10:03:32
```

I want all rows from `table1` where `date(create_dt) >= '2017-01-07'` and
`table1.a_id = table2.a_id` and `table2.check1 = 'FAIL'`
Also, `I only want to consider the row from table2` with latest `timestamp_val`

So from the above example, my query should return

```
a_id    ip              create_dt
9205    10.10.10.10     2017-01-07 08:03:32
```

I have written the following query and `want to know how to incorporate the logic to consider the row from table2 with latest 'timestamp_val'`

```
SELECT
  *
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b
  ON a.a_id = b.a_id
  AND DATE(a.create_dt) >= '2017-01-07'
  AND b.check_status = 'FAIL'
  AND b.check_type = 'check1'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `date()` function doesn't do anything for you.  Also, the individual comparisons would normally be in a `where` clause.

You can then do what you want with an additional condition in the `where` clause:

```
SELECT *  
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN
     table2 b
     ON a.a_id = b.a_id
WHERE a.create_dt >= '2017-01-07' AND
      b.check_status = 'FAIL' AND
      b.check_type = 'check1' AND
      b.timestamp_val = (SELECT MAX(b2.timestamp_val)
                         FROM table2 b2
                         WHERE b2.a_id = b.a_id AND
                               b2.check_status = b.check_status AND
                               b2.check_type = b.check_type
                        );
```

Comment: I am not getting the correct result using this query. I guess for some rows it is not taking the max value of the column `timestamp_val`

Comment: @meallhour. . . . This is the maximum value of the timestamp that meets the three conditions.  Perhaps I misinterpreted the question and the conditions on `check_status` and `check_type` are not needed.

Comment: can you please update the answer so that i get a better understanding on what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *  
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b
  ON a.a_id = b.a_id
    AND date(a.create_dt) >= '2017-01-07'
    AND b.check_status = 'FAIL'
    AND b.check_type = 'check1'
ORDER BY timestamp_val desc 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: this will always return only 1 record. I think it is not useful.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.